# регулярки для проверки широты и долготы в градусах с десятичной дробью

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, координаты

Так понимаю, что у широты макс 8 символов, 6 из которых идут после точки и знак "-",
а у долготы макс 9 символов, 6 идут после точки и знак "-".

```
preg_match('/^\d{2}.\d{6}$/D', $_GET['latitude'])
preg_match('/^\d{3}.\d{6}$/D', $_GET['longitude'])

// 57.904683, -122.210420
```

Если верно, то как правильно указать необязательный "минус" в `preg_match`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необязательный минус указывается в регулярном выражении с помощью квантификатора `?`:

```
^-?\d{2}\.\d{6}$
```

- `^` - начало строки
- `-?` - 1 или 0 минусов (квантификатор `?` делает подшаблон необязательным)
- `\d{2}` - 2 цифры
- `\.` - точка (этот знак нужно экранировать, т.к. это спецсимвол, отлавливающий любой символ кроме знаков перевода строки)
- `\d{6}` - 6 цифр
- `$` - конец строки (или `\z`, чтобы не использовать `/D`)

Comment: Какие символы требуют экранирования? В описании функции `preg_quote` нашел: "служебными считаются следующие символы: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`" - это они?

Comment: Это зависит от того, находятся ли эти символы внутри символьного класса или нет, и в каком месте в символьном классе они находятся. Точно следует экранировать разделители. Вне символьных классов надо экранировать обязательно `?`, `+`, `*`, `|`, `(`, `)`, `[`, `^`, `$`, ``\``, `.`, а также `#` и пробел (если задан модификатор VERBOSE). Желательно экранировать `{`. Внутри символьного класса нужно экранировать `]`, `-`, `^`, ``\``. Если минус в начале или в конце симв. класса, не надо его экранировать. Если `]`  в начале, тоже не надо.

Comment: (Я надеюсь, это не вы в одиночку проголосовали за некоторые из моих ответов (кажется, четыре)? Иначе эти очки завтра "сгорят")

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. первые цифры могут быть в диапазоне от 1 до 3 то это тоже необходимо указать. `{1,3}`
Минус `-?` 0 или 1

```
preg_match('/^-?\d{1,2}\.\d{6}$/D', $_GET['latitude'])
preg_match('/^-?\d{1,3}\.\d{6}$/D', $_GET['longitude'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{6}$/D', $_GET['latitude'])
preg_match('/^\-[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{6}$/D', $_GET['longitude'])
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?